# Want to change a -z to b-z

Tags: java

1. Question

   My input is `aaasssuuu`, but my output is `aaasssvvv`;
   What I want is `bbbtttvvv`. So what's wrong with my code ?
2. Code

   ```
   class Solution{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String str = "aaasssuuu";   
           System.out.println(functionalShiftLetters(str));
       }

       public static String functionalShiftLetters(String str){
           String ss = new String();
           for(int i =0; i<=str.length()-1 ;i++)
               sb = str.replace((char)str.charAt(i), (char) (str.charAt(i)+1));

           return ss;
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Paste code as code and fix indentation, it'll make people more likely to review your question.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Where is `sb` defined?

Comment: So you want a "ROT(1)"?

Comment: `sb` is not defined, please fix.

Comment: You create string ss but do nothing with it. 
You have sb  =  ...   
I am guessing change sb to ss.

Comment: you're not reinjecting changes to `str` in `str`. Are you sure this is the code you're running?

Comment: Tip: `i < str.length()` is cleaner and more standard than `i<=str.length()-1`.

Comment: If you're going to iterate over each character in the string then just append each new character to `ss` instead of calling `String#replace` on each iteration.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, of course, that's the bug.

Comment: `new String()` <- never do this.

Comment: THank you so much guys,  I got it now ,  big hug

Comment: What if I wanna z to be a ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the string, and instead of using `.replace()` you can add one to the ASCII value instead. This is the change method:

```
public static String functionalShiftLetters(String str){
    String ss = new String();
    for(int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++){
      ss += (char)((str.charAt(x) + 1)) + "";
    }
    return ss;
}
```

You can make this quicker by using `StringBuilder` and the `.append()` which gives O(1) insertion.

Comment: Whoops, typo, fixed.

Comment: No problem, once you find the answer that helped you most make sure to mark it as answered.

Comment: what if I wanna z to be a ??

Comment: I would encourage you to play with ASCII manipulation. Try doing stuff like (char)('z' - (something)) and (char)('a' - (something)) and see how they work out.

Comment: TY   I just make it

Comment: First, a string is a sequence of UTF-16 code units not ASCII. Second, I would _discourage_ you from manipulating code units or codepoints with arithmetic. If it works it's only a fluke because you are focusing on the ordered sequence of lowercase letters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block. Real-world text is not like that—not even just English text.

Answer (score 1):

With **Java 8**:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aaasssuuu";
    str.chars() 
        .mapToObj(x -> (char) (x + 1)) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

with **java 6**:

```
char[] w = str.toCharArray();

    for (char c : w) {
        System.out.println((char) (c + 1));
    }
```

Comment: what if I wanna z to be a  ??

Answer (score 0):

Since no one's answering the question, your mistake is that you're using `str` to replace, but never updating `str`, so only the last replace takes effect. Update your code to replace on the same variable you're updating:

```
public static String functionalShiftLetters(String str){
    for(int i =0; i<=str.length()-1 ;i++)
        str = str.replace((char)str.charAt(i), (char) (str.charAt(i)+1));

    return str;
}
```

HT [@Jean-FrançoisFabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045121/wanna-change-a-z-to-b-z-a#comment65440030_39045121)

Answer (score 0):

```
         class Solution{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "aaassszzz";
            str.chars() 
            .mapToObj(c -> (char)(c + 1) > 'z' ? 'a' :(char)(c+1) ) 
            .forEach(System.out::print);
            }
            }
```